# Angular2 Router Issues

Tags: angular, localhost, dashboard, angular2-routing, pageload

I'm starting a project, anticipating scope change during initial development. Angular2 seemed like a good choice for prototyping the site with mock data, to later add persistence services.

Having completed the tutorial on their site, however, I've come across a problem: when navigating to the site root, on successive requests the root route redirect is repeatedly appended to the request.

This seems to work in a messy sort of way until the third page load, after which the page sits on "Loading...", presumably trying to load

> localhost/Dashboard/Dashboard/Dashboard.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: If you could edit your question to include route definitions, and any router links, that would help us. Thanks!

Comment: @R.Richards here is a link to a plinker of the exact code I'm using, from the angular 2 tutorial: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also. I believe that it is coming from the script in index.html that is used to generate `<base href="/">`

To solve the problem go to **index.html** and replace

```
<script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
```

With

```
<base href="/">
```

However I am not sure yet what effect this will have elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Add a leading `/` to the path you navigate to, to indicate that the path starts from root. Alternatively `../` can be used to start from the parent route.